# How can I get infinite maximum execution time with PHP?

Tags: php, execution-time

I have a site with 2000 pages and I want to iterate through each page to generate a sitemap, using the `file_get_html()` function and regular expressions.

Obviously this can't be completed in one server-side execution as it will run out of time due to maximum execution time. I guess it needs to perform smaller actions, save the progress to the database and then queue the next task. Any suggestions?

Comment: A quick side answer: this depends on your hosting provider

Comment: I assume the hosting provider doesn't let you change the execution time (i.e. [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) doesn't work)? Although this sounds like you could run the script once/periodically on your own computer and upload the resulting page.

Comment: Juhana: even if they would allow to change PHP's time limit to 0, there's always a question of webserver terminating connections, and also there's a possibility that hosting has some system in place that kills long running PHP threads.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you run it command line there will be no maximum execution time.

You can also use `set_time_limit(0);` for this if your provider allows manipulation.

I can't tell if your ip-address will get banned - as this depends on the security of the server you send your requests to.

---

**Other solution**

You can fetch one (or a few) page(s), and search for new URLs throughout the source code. You can then queue these in a database. Then on the next run, you process the queue.

Comment: you should increase the time limit rather than setting it to 0=infinite as this may yield with ghost processes.

Comment: Thanks Wesley. Ideally I'd like to get the results as they progress. Another example is that a search engine spider wouldn't crawl the entire internet in one execution. There must be a way to break up a complex action into smaller ones and queue the executions. Any ideas?

Comment: @Imre I agree, I would definitly advise against this.

Comment: Your other solution sounds good. Although I'm not sure how to trigger queues in php. I assume that using a cron isn't the most elegant way. Shoan has suggested Gearman or zeromq. I'll check them out and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using a Job queue and worker implementation. I would recommend [Gearman](http://gearman.org/#introduction) or [zeromq](http://zeromq.org). Both of these have native php bindings.

Answer (score 3):

Use `set_time_limit(0)`. See the **[PHP Manual](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)** for more detailed explanation.

> seconds
>
> > The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

EDIT: As for your second question, it's not likely, however, you should check your hosting services Terms of Use to see if it's allowed.

Comment: Please use -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

I would have edited post, but the edit was too small for me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Set max_execution_time to 0 in your php.ini. It will affect every script you run on the server, but if you're looking for a server-level fix, this will do it.

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

```
max_execution_time = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way for you is use remot api .
for example you can use import.io and get param from each page with json format . 
this is a way to get light page on each call for file_get_content or flie_get_html

but for this issu curl is beter than file_get_html