# save bit of realtime data 4 times per day with php without human interaction

Tags: php, timed

We're building an application that uses data from an api. We don't want to proces all this data because it's too much. We want to capture the data 4 times per day. Therefore we need a php script that saves this to the database without a button or human help.

We know how to get the data and understand how to upload this to a database. We don't know how to do this timed and if this is even possible.

We tried to do this with this code, but the page needs to be refreshed to echo.

```
if (date('His') == 114300) {
  echo date('His');
}
```

Comment: did you set up a cron job for this on your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PHP script only runs when it's called via a request from a browser or another client, or when run through the command line.

You could, in theory, create a script with [infinite execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036767/php-infinite-maximum-execution-time), and have that  running. The script would need to check the server time and make the requests. The problem would be that it'd stop if the server restarted, etc. It's also highly inefficient.

Just call your script with a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), four times a day, e.g. like so:

```
0 */6 * * * curl -k http://example.com/download.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The `/6` means *every six hours*. The `curl` command calls the script and `>/dev/null` discards the output.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I can only manually change the cron settings. I've set it to 2 minutes to test. This is the output. */02 * * * * www.example.com/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1   it's not working by the way.

Comment: `www.example.com/…` is not a valid command. You have to put actual shell commands into the crontab, e.g. `curl -k …` — not just the URL of a website. (By the way, "not working" is not a useful problem description, please try and be more detailed.)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is by creating a cron job that runs 4 times a day

```
0  13,14,15,16  *       *       *       /usr/bin/php path/to/cron.php &> /dev/null
```

your path/to/cron.php will be run at 13:00, 14:00, 15:00 and 16:00

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/

Answer (score 1):

If you have a server (standalone / vps, with shell access), install a cron job.

If you have cpanel access, find the cron job setting.