# set_time_limit(0) but stops execution after 1 hour

Tags: php, apache2, configuration-files

I'm writing a migration script which needs some time to run through. It starts with set_time_limit(0) and after each step I flush(); / ob_flush(); the output, but it always stops after 1 hour of execution.

Any idea which setting is responsible for this behavior? Environment: PHP 5.5 and Apache2.

Thanks!

Comment: You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036767/php-infinite-maximum-execution-time Where do you run this script? On your PC or on some hosting?

Comment: Assuming you're running this from the command line (and not through a webserver with its own timeout), then either you've reset the timelimit somewhere inside your script and it has been reached, or the script has completed successfully, or it's failed with an error (check the logs)

Comment: If it's a script that takes an hour or more to run, then you certainly shouldn't be running it through a webserver

Comment: You should also check in php.ini max_execution_time and try to set it to 0. But in fact, the best way is to dividing the script and run it in some type of cron job than running script without time limits